# Saving Option Menu Shared Preferences

Tags: android, shared, sharedpreferences

I have a option menu. When the activity loses focus, the selected option menu item(s) retain state, but when my activity is destroyed, all the options are reset.

How can I save the state of the selected preference after resuming from a destroyed state? Having problem visualizing how to implement [Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) for the code.

(Only needed for the boolean values but I have included the static menu items.)

```
public final static int MENU_SOMETHING_MODE_ON = 1;
public final static int MENU_SOMETHING_MODE_OFF = 2;
public final static int MENU_FULLSCREEN_ON = 3;
public final static int MENU_FULLSCREEN_OFF = 4;
public final static int MENU_SOUND_ON = 5;
public final static int MENU_SOUND_OFF = 6;
public final static int MENU_FASTER = 7;
public final static int MENU_SLOWER = 8;
public final static int MENU_SOMETHING = 9;
public final static int MENU_EXTRAS = 10;

private static boolean soundOn = true;
private static boolean mFaster = true;

private boolean fullscreen = true;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    menu.add(0, MENU_SOMETHING, 0, R.string.menu_new_something);
    menu.add(0, MENU_SOMETHING_MODE_ON, 0,
             R.string.menu_something_on);
    menu.add(0, MENU_SOMETHING_MODE_OFF, 0,
             R.string.menu_something_off);
    menu.add(0, MENU_FULLSCREEN_ON, 0, R.string.menu_fullscreen_on);
    menu.add(0, MENU_FULLSCREEN_OFF, 0, R.string.menu_fullscreen_off);
    menu.add(0, MENU_SOUND_ON, 0, R.string.menu_sound_on);
    menu.add(0, MENU_SOUND_OFF, 0, R.string.menu_sound_off);
    menu.add(0, MENU_FASTER, 0, R.string.menu_faster);
    menu.add(0, MENU_SLOWER, 0, R.string.menu_slower);
    menu.add(0, MENU_EXTRAS, 0, R.string.menu_extras);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    menu.findItem(MENU_SOUND_ON).setVisible(!getSoundOn());
    menu.findItem(MENU_SOUND_OFF).setVisible(getSoundOn());
    menu.findItem(MENU_SOMETHING_ON).setVisible(
        getMode() == SOMETHING_NORMAL);
    menu.findItem(MENU_SOMETHING_OFF).setVisible(
        getMode() != SOMETHING_NORMAL);
    menu.findItem(MENU_FULLSCREEN_ON).setVisible(!fullscreen);
    menu.findItem(MENU_FULLSCREEN_OFF).setVisible(fullscreen);
    menu.findItem(MENU_FASTER).setVisible(getFaster());
    menu.findItem(MENU_SLOWER).setVisible(!getFaster());
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case MENU_SOMETHING:

     AlertDialog.Builder alt_bld = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);   

     alt_bld.setMessage("Are you sure?")
     .setCancelable(false)
     .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                 //  Action for 'YES' Button
                 something.new();
             }
      })
     .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                 //  Action for 'NO' Button
                 dialog.cancel();
             }
      });
      AlertDialog alert = alt_bld.create();
      // Title for AlertDialog
      alert.setTitle("Something");
      // Icon for AlertDialog
      alert.setIcon(R.drawable.dialog);
      alert.show();


      return true;
    case MENU_SOMETHING_ON:
      setMode(THIS_SOMETHING);
      return true;
    case MENU_SOMETHING_OFF:
      setMode(THIS_NORMAL);
      return true;
    case MENU_FULLSCREEN_ON:
      fullscreen = true;
      setFullscreen();
      return true;
    case MENU_FULLSCREEN_OFF:
      fullscreen = false;
      setFullscreen();
      return true;
    case MENU_SOUND_ON:
      setSoundOn(true);
      return true;
    case MENU_SOUND_OFF:
      setSoundOn(false);
      return true;
    case MENU_FASTER:
      setFaster(false);
      return true;
    case MENU_SLOWER:
      setSlower(true);
      return true;
    case MENU_EXTRAS:
      startExtras();
      return true;
    }
    return false;
}

private void setFullscreen()
{
    if (fullscreen) {
      getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
      getWindow().clearFlags(
          WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
    } else {
      getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
      getWindow().addFlags(
          WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
    }
    mView.requestLayout();
}

public synchronized static void setMode(int newMode)
{
    Mode = newMode;
}

public synchronized static int getMode()
{
    return Mode;
}

public synchronized static boolean getSoundOn()
{
    return soundOn;
}

public synchronized static void setSoundOn(boolean so)
{
    soundOn = so;
}

public synchronized static boolean getFaster()
{
    return Faster;
}

public synchronized static void setFaster(boolean dont)
{
    Faster = dont;
}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

[This is a fantastic tutorial](http://www.kaloer.com/android-preferences) on how to create a preference activity along with how to get/set these preferences.  It will also show you how to use shared preferences if you choose not to implement a preference activity.

Almost all users are familiar with a preference activity because it is how they adjust settings on their phone.

While not the only way to implement "options," or possibly perhaps not even the best way, it works great, has a ton of flexibility, and is simple and quick to implement.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer but I would prefer to save option menu with in the current code framework.

Comment: Link is dead, just another reason my posting a link as the answer is not a good idea.